# Network resource access control (maybe using VLANs?)

Tags: routing, dhcp, vlan, access-control, network-discovery

I'm trying to set up a network that has a couple of different device groups with different access rights. Physically, devices are connected to the network either via wall-ports or via one of several available WiFi networks. The hardware I'm using are a couple of Cisco SG200-08 smart switches, a set of UniFi WiFi APs, and an EdgeRouter Lite, that runs a fork of Vyatta-Linux called EdgeOS.

Since there is quite some flux in the connected devices, I would like to not have to maintain a MAC address list to manage access rights, but rather assign the devices implicitly to a group simply based on which wall-port or WiFi network I connect them to.

My current thought of how to do this is the following:

- Define different VLANs for the different device groups (for simplicity, let's say VLAN 10 for trusted systems with full access and VLAN 20 for guests that are only allowed to access certain resources).
- The smart switches can then automatically assign VLAN IDs to the different wall-ports.
- Turns out the UniFi APs can broadcast up to 4 WiFi networks simultaneously with different access credentials and then tag traffic with VLAN IDs depending on which WiFi network it came from.
- Finally, the EdgeRouter ties it all together by managing access rights for the different VLANs.

The problem I have is that some devices I have use various methods of auto-discovery to be found by their access software (UPNP, Windows network shares, proprietary protocols, ...). I would like for the devices that are accessible by everyone (from VLAN 10 and 20) to also be discoverable by everyone (i.e. from both VLANs). Thus, I need to find a way to forward broadcasts correctly and maybe do a couple other things as well...

Here's where I'm currently at with my thoughts on how to do that:

- Set up a DHCP server that assigns values in 192.168.**10**.0/**24** to VLAN 10
- Set up a second DHCP server that assigns values in 192.168.**20**.0/**24** to VLAN 20
- Have the DHCP servers tell their clients that the subnet mask is 255.255.**0**.0 (to hopefully prompt them to try to discover devices in both address ranges)
- Set up ARP proxying and broadcast packet forwarding between the VLANs (not sure yet how to achieve this. Maybe just bridge the 2 VLANs?)
- Add firewall rules that drop all cross-VLAN-packets, except for broadcast-packets or packets whose VLAN-10-IP matches a device that should be accessible by guests also.

So, here are my questions:

1. Does the setup the way I described it above make any sense at all, or is there an entirely different, better way to achieve the access control? (I would definitely like to keep the convenience of implicitly assigning computers to the different access groups by simply connecting them to one of several available WiFi networks or plugging them into specific wall-ports.)
2. Would the setup I described indeed allow (UPNP-)device discovery across VLANs? How about Windows computers and their network shares?
3. Is it possible in Linux to have a DHCP server assign addresses in one subnet (e.g. 192.168.10.0/24), but provide a different subnet mask to its clients (e.g. 255.255.0.0)?

   Extra credit: Can I do this from the EdgeOS GUI on my EdgeRouter somehow, or do I need to set this up from the command line?
4. Do I just set up a generic bridge between the VLANs and drop "illegal" packets, or is there a better way (safer, better performance, ...) to link the two networks to allow for device discovery and access?
5. Is it possible to just create two completely independent VLANs (no bridging) and simply have the router "map" a device into the other network? I.e. "fake" a system with IP address 192.168.20.5 in VLAN 20 and simply forward all its traffic to the real system at 192.168.10.5 in VLAN 10? Can this be done so that there is no difference between the mapped virtual system vs having that system actually connected to the network under the respective other IP?

One more thing to note: Not all devices that I need to share across networks run Linux. So I can't just go and "connect" the devices to both VLANs via virtual interfaces like eth0.10 and eth0.20.

PS: I've read that VLANs are not the most secure way to provide access controls since there are several easy ways to hack them (double-tagging, etc). But it sounded like with a little care to avoid native IDs and trunk ports, these can be easily prevented. Are there other, more fundamental reasons NOT to use VLANs for this purpose? If so, what would be an alternative?

Comment: What if you set up the fully available devices in VLAN30 , and allowed any traffic from VLAN10 and 20, just not between them?

Comment: I was thinking something like that: To have the restricted resources simply on VLAN-10 and the public resources on VLAN-30 and then allow traffic between 10 and 30 and between 20 and 30, but not between 10 and 20. I just don't know yet how I would make auto-discovery work across VLANs in that case. Also, if I simply create two bridges: 10-30 and 20-30, would that implicitly also bridge 10 and 20?

Comment: It shouldn't bridge them implicitly, but you'd probably want some sort of rules denying traffic between the networks (by IP should work). BTW, both windows and linux can handle multiple NICs or multiple IP addresses.. or you could just do two NAT sessions between 10<->30 and 20<->30 so you could present the shared resources in both with local IP addresses.

Comment: Can you do device auto-discovery across NATs, though?